How to define API response globally in NestJS Swagger documentation?
I want 500 Internal Server Error to appear in all endpoints, is there anyway to do that globally without having to add @ApiInternalServerErrorResponse() on all the controller methods

here you can see a hacky approach to that problem: NestJS tip: how to attach decorators to all controllers at once 
